# Clojure File System

Tags: file, download, clojure, upload, system

I am a near-beginner in Clojure, and especially the web development world of Clojure. I currently have a Clojure project that, when run on `leiningen`, allows me to open a `localhost` browser and go to the routes I have specified.
One of the routes I am working on is a **File Uploading** route -- I allow the user to choose a file from their computer and click **Submit** -- Which reroutes to a new page showing the file name as well as the size of the file. Furthermore, it copy's the file to `/resources/public/Files` inside the project directory. I want to then be able to go to a different webpage and list all of the files inside of `/resources/public/Files` as links for downloading so that in the long run, **Users** on one end can upload files and on the other end, other **Users** can download the files that were uploaded. Is there an easy Clojure library to use to do this?
Thank you very much

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail? What libraries/framework/template are you currently using for your project? A code snippet of what you've tried would be helpful as well.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you should take a look at the functions in the `clojure.java.io` namespace. Specifically the [resource](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.io/resource) function might help you achieve what you want.

Comment: @jsonmurphy I'm building it on a Luminus framework

Comment: @Logan I don't think there is a library that does this. Are you using a database with the framework? If so you could just store a record in some **Files** table with the path to each uploaded file, then simply retrieve the records and present them to the users. This may require that you add something like `(route/resources "/")` to your routes, but again, without seeing the code its difficult to recommend a solid approach.

Comment: @jsonmurphy Yes, I'm using a database with the framework. I have now stored the files in a table in the database, though it only stores file names at the moment.. How would I go about storing the path to each uploaded file? The uploaded file seems to come in as a map, with :filename :size :content-type and :tempfile right now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you get a copy of this book, [Web Development with Clojure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1937785645). It is the best one on the subject that I have seen and will give you the overview that you need.

[image]

Comment: I started to read into this book, though I'm building my website on a Luminus framework so I found it to be quite different -- However, I will look back into it. Thanks for the information